# How to NOT reset section numbering after a new chapter?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters, books

I'm translating a book where the author originally wrote the section numbering straight through the chapters, without resetting the numbering, and I wanted to keep this original structure. In the original, the table of contents is like,

```
 1. First chapter
   1.1 First Section
   1.2 Second section
 2. Second Chapter
   2.1 Third section
   2.2 Fourth section
```

and so on. I have tried every thing I could but the section numbers keep resetting after a new chapter.

Comment: Your example is confusing. You're showing a reset section counter with the name of the section 2.1 being "Third section". That would just mean you use `\section{Third section}` without changing the counter in any way. Please clarify.

Comment: @Marino I have edited the answer. It should clarify a few things, which I omit in the first version. Specifically, you may want to use the starred version of the macro, which redefines `\thesection` and remove chapter numbers from it or non-starred version and keep the numbering unchanged. I also pointed to two places with more information about counters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be achieved using `counterwithout`

---

EDIT. A couple of remarks.

The package `chngcntr` is required before Apr 2018 of LaTeX (see [LaTeX2e News Issue 28](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2018/04/10/issue28-of-latex2e-news-released/)).

`\counterwithout*` has an unstarred version `\counterwithout[format]{counter}{within counter}`, which automatically removes `within counter` if the optional argument is omitted; particularly, in the solution, chapters would no longer appear as a part of section numbering. If this is the desired effect, then `\counterwithout` should be used, instead.

For more information see the reference: [source2e](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/source2e.pdf) (the section *"ltcounts.dtx"* p. 400). Also, there is a website [Counters](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Counters) on Overleaf, which provides some explanation with a few examples.

---

```latex
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}   % Before Apr 2018 LaTeX

\counterwithout*{section}{chapter}   % Section numbering remains unchanged
% \counterwithout{section}{chapter}   % Redefines section numbering


\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\section{X}
\section{Y}

\chapter{B}
\section{Y}
\section{Z}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. However, I think that `\counterwithout` rather than `\counterwithout*` is what's needed to meet the OP's formatting objective. Aside: You may want to mention that the `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` macros were integrated into the LaTeX kernel in the spring of 2018. (Maybe more famously, the spring 2018 release of the LaTeX format made `utf8` the default input encoding; since then, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is the default.) Hence, loading the `chngcntr` package is needed only if one is still using a version of the LaTeX format dated 2017 or even older.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comment. I edited the answer and addressed the issues.

Comment: I think your suggestion would've worked better, but I've found a way of doing the desired effect and for now I won't use in this project, but I'll try in the future with others. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

After think a bit I have accomplished the effect I wanted, by doing the following

```
    \let\OldSection\section
    \renewcommand*{\section}[1]{\OldSection{#1}\stepcounter{secCount}}
    \newcounter{secCount}
    \setcounter{secCount}{1}
    \renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{secCount}}
```

I don't know if is the most effective or the correct way, but in this specific case worked very well.